# why my spring session scoped bean is shared across sessions?

Tags: java, spring, session, scope, session-scope

i have a simple pojo `UserQuota` with 1 field `quota` in it:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public interface UserQuota {
    public int getQuota();
    public void setQuota(int quota);
}
```

now, i used two different browser windows (firefox and chrome) to log into my web application as two different users. to my surprise, when i set the value of quota (with `setQuota`) from one session, the new value becomes available to the other session (when `getQuota` is called). i was expecting each user session will have its own bean instance; isn't that what session scoped bean in spring is for?

i must be missing something. what could it be?

edit:

the implementation class looks like this:

```
@Component
public class UserQuotaImpl implements UserQuota {

    private int quota;

    /**
     * @return the quota
     */
    public int getQuota() {
        return quota;
    }

    /**
     * @param quota the quota to set
     */
    public void setQuota(int quota) {
        this.quota = quota;
    }

}
```

and finally here is how i use the session bean:

```
@Component
public class UserQuotaHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserQuota userQuota;

    public void checkAndUpdateQuota() {
        int quota = userQuota.getQuota();

        // i use my business logic to decide whether the quota needs an update
        if(myBusinessLogic) {
            userQuota.setQuota(someNewValue);
        }
    }

}
```

i am using `context:component-scan` in my xml config file. it may be noted that most of my other autowired beans are singleton beans which seem to have been working as expected

Comment: Please show how you inject and use the bean.

Comment: i have updated my question as requested

Comment: Where is the implementation class? You'll want to annotate that with the `@Scope`, not the interface, afaik.

Comment: i included my implementation class in the question. let me check what happens if i move the `@Scope` annotation from interface to implementation. will get back with the outcome

Comment: excellent. that was it. now i am getting the expected behavior. many thanks. can you please post the solution as an answer so that i can accept it; also if you could add a bit of explanation / reference to why it doesn't work when the interface is annotated, that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to annotate your concrete bean class with the session `@Scope`, `UserQuotaImpl` in your case.

Spring ignores the `@Scope` on any superclasses or superinterfaces of your concrete class. Since your type doesn't have any explicit `@Scope` annotations

```
@Component
public class UserQuotaImpl implements UserQuota {
```

Spring assumes you meant to make it a singleton bean.

Comment: that means my request scoped beans are having the same problem, too! it's just that the problem with the session scoped bean came to the surface first

Comment: @Tanvir In general, don't assume that annotations are ever "inherited".